# How can i check if the FCM Token is still valid, with cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, web, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to check if a token is still valid before sending an FCM notification with cloud functions. How can I do it ?

Comment: When you call the API to send a message to tokens, it'll tell you which tokens have expired. That is the most common way to clean up expired tokens. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49049399/verify-stored-firebase-fcm-tokens If you want to make an explicit, additional call just for the check, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50739301/fcm-verify-device-token-before-sending-push-notification-using-php